# Есть вопрос: можно или нет переместить навигацию OwlCarousel 2 на блоки с другими классами, или в дрйгой блок?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, owl-carousel

Можно или нет переместить навигацию OwlCarousel 2 на блоки с другими классами, или в дрйгой блок?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отключаете стандартную навигацию и вешаете триггеры на те элементы, которые потребуются:

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel();
$('.customNextBtn').click(function() {
    owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
})
$('.customPrevBtn').click(function() {
    owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel', [300]); // в квадратных скобках скорость переключения
})
```

Из официальной документации: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вы лучший!